# C# codes doesn't work in host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, hosting, publishing

I open the website(The website created with MVC). I get compilation error. How can i fix this error?  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you miss `web.config` file in `Views` directory?

Comment: What must i do web.config in views?

Comment: Web.config used for overriding high-level web.config. In Views folder it's used for importing namespaces and block attempts to request view directly (without controller). It's better to use web.config from empty folder.